# Akka: how to config Router, dispatcher to make a better performance?

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka

I have played around akka for two weeks and still very confused with some basic concept.

I have a very simple pattern which contains three kinds of actors:

- master
- worker
- reporter

I config these actors as following:

### Master

Master use following dispatcher with RoundRobinRouter(10):

```
mailbox-capacity = 10000
executor = "fork-join-executor"
fork-join-executor {
  parallelism-min = 0
  parallelism-max = 600
  parallelism-factor = 3.0
}
```

### Worker

I have several workers(ref) in this system, they all receive messages from master, and each of them use a router of RoundRobinRouter(10).

```
type = Dispatcher
executor = "fork-join-executor"
fork-join-executor {
  parallelism-min = 0
  parallelism-max = 600
  parallelism-factor = 3.0
}
mailbox-capacity = 100000
```

### Notifier

is just an actor used to receive result from the worker, and counting up.
It uses the same dispatcher as workers.

I have made some adjustment on the parallelism parameters and router, but the performance seems no change. It takes 80 seconds to consume 10 million tasks, of each takes at least 500 ms to finish.

So it got me there, if a dispatcher acts like a thread pool, what if an actor use this dispatcher without using a router, which means there is only one instance. Will the code in receive block be executed parallel?

Just in case something else in my code messed things up: 
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/visualskyrim/00d519e55399b676ae5b)

And this is the virtual machine runs this program:

- 32-bit ubuntu 12.04 lts
- Memory 5.0 GiB
- Intel® Core™ i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz × 4

Sorry to put this question so unclear here. 
If there is any thing can improve this performance please tell me.
Any advise is welcome. Thank in advance.

### Update

Sorry!
It was 10 million task, not 100 million!
My bad, sorry!

Comment: I didn't see your config file in that Gist. Can you make that available too?

Comment: Tuning the performance of an actor system is a hard task. But without knowing what the task is (e.g. does it do any blocking operations, read from IO, ...) it is hard to tell what to do or if anything can be done at all. Looking at the numbers it seems that you already have a high level of parallelism, since performing 100 Million 500ms tasks sequentially would take much longer than 80 seconds. So the question rather is, what is your aim. If 80 seconds is fast enough for your use case, I would not try to further tune it unless you have a good reason for doing so.

Comment: You only have 4 cores in your machine. Are all of the cores working at nearly 100%? Do you create a lot of garbage during processing? You could attach jconsole and/or enable gc logs to see if something is wrong there.

Comment: @cmbaxter config file is almost the same as I put in the question. But I have updated the gist file.

Comment: @CarstenSaathoff Yes, you make the point. But things that confuse me is that no matter how I adjust the config and the router, the performance seems to show no change at all. I want to know the bottleneck of this code.

Comment: @drexin Thanks for response! Yes, they are. All processors are fully occupied when program starts. In this program there is no object being created except the actors, all the tasks are just scheduled and print a line. So I am not sure it is a gc issue.

Comment: Okay, I think your problem is IO. Try doing something else instead and I guarantee you it will be faster.

Comment: If all processors are occupied and the task you are performing is CPU-bound, i.e., no disk/network io is happening, you are probably at the maximum possible performance. Of course, there could still be potential for optimizations. Maybe you have too many context switches or too many threads running, and reducing the number of overall threads would even improve performance. However, I don't think there are any useful suggestion we can make when we don't see what exactly is going on.

Comment: Thank you guys very much! As @CarstenSaathoff and drexin put here, it seems to be context switch issue, so I reducing the number of parallel max and system became slightly faster. Maybe it is be maximum possible performance. Thank you guys again!

Comment: Another improvement could be to eliminate the two custom dispatchers and run everything through the default dispatcher in your actor system.  That will reduce the number of threads running and thus the load on your CPUs. As long as none of the actors were doing blocking io then I don't see a great need for separate dispatchers.